# Why were my tag edits rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday I edited some tags.  They were all rejected.  In my opinion, they were improvements to the current tags.  The tags I edited were either empty or just one liners: "Questions relating to so and so..."

I essentially copied some of the text from Wikipedia, a practice widely used on other SE sites, and referenced the page.  Granted, this is not an ideal tag entry, but I think it is better than nothing.  Is it preferable to have either a blank entry or a one-liner until we get an entry like what is described [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy/Paste from Wikipedia isn't the preferred thing, and in fact, has been heavily abused on Stack Exchange as a whole. I will approve some entries from Wikipedia, but only if they can be shown to make this site better. Remember, the tag wikis are for our benefit, to help us first of all separate out what the purpose of the tag is, and secondly to give a brief bit of introduction to the subject. If they don't do the first, then it's just not as helpful as it could otherwise be.

Comment: Well said. I would also add: the argument that "it's better than nothing" only discourages users who would otherwise see a blank tag wiki as motivation to write a proper entry — **[Improved Tagging](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)**.

Comment: Thanks.  I will endeavour to write better tags.